# Facebook tab app on page not showing for all users (including admins)

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page, iframe-app

I have a tab app on a Facebook page that works only for SOME users. I am not sure what the distinction is because one of these users is an admin. SSL is working fine and its not in sandbox mode. Is there any reason why it would show a blank page for some people?

Here is the URL https://www.facebook.com/pages/Purple-Haze-l-Warehouse-Rave-Series/414833951888732?sk=app_263980683718092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SSL is working fine

Yes, but the none-SSL version isn’t.

`https://exterbox.com/dev/ravetv/` is the URL for your SSL version of your app – so I guess `http://exterbox.com/dev/ravetv/` is supposed to be the non-SSL version, but calling that just gives a 404 Not Found error.